# How to use boost::any type in luabind (lua, c++)?

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

In c++, i have a function that return boost::any type , in Lua i called this function (throught luabind) but get error "crep && you are trying to use an unregistered type"

I used : lua 5.1.5, luabind 0.8

Comment: Can't you just... register the type? It's not clear what the problem here is. Are you having trouble registering it? It isn't a template, and it's not really a type that Lua is equipped to use.

Comment: Thanks for reply : my problem is : my function return multiple type (int, float, double, string..). Before each other type i have function override then i tried use boost::any . Is there other way ?